# Open app scheme from app

Tags: android, url-scheme

In my Android app I want to open an app scheme. For example:

- `whatsapp://send?text=Hallo`
- `onepassword://`

I know how to open a specific package name by Intent but I have no idea how to open an app scheme in an app. I know it's possible from a browser.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#Build